# How do I fix scapular winging?

Tags: shoulders, back, shoulder-cuff

I have a winged scapular on my left shoulder blade for many years. I start working out around two years ago. Sometime the winged scapular will disappear and someday it pops out again. I need a solid solution for this.

Comment: To treat winging, we need to see your body, more specifically your posture. It would also help to get an x-ray to see what's going on internally. One paragraph of text doesn't cut it. This is why doctors exist.

Comment: Athlean X had a good video on how to fix it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VCPp1DUypo0&t=492s